# What is the format for the defaultSelectedUser property for this People Picker?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying to populate this people picker with multiple users stored in seperate Person columns in an SP list.

This is the control: https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/

And the property is the defaultSelectedUsers, I use this to populate the PP when an item is retrieved from the SP list.
Here is the People picker:

```
<PeoplePicker
   context={this.props.context}
   personSelectionLimit={3}
   groupName={''} // Leave this blank in case you want to filter from all users
   showtooltip={false}
   isRequired={false}
   disabled={false}
   selectedItems={this._getPanellistsPickerItems}
   showHiddenInUI={false}
   defaultSelectedUsers={panellists ? panellists : []}
   principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
   resolveDelay={1000}
   ensureUser={true}
  />
```

The panellists is an array which output looks like this:

```
(3) ["user02@domain.co.uk", "user01@domain.co.uk", "user03@domain.co.uk"]
0: "user02@domain.co.uk"
1: "user01@domain.co.uk"
2: "user03@domain.co.uk"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But it's not putting anything into the PP on retrieval. I'm stringifying the array, but not sure if that's the correct format for the aforementioned property.

Comment: Could you share the function to get people name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tom,

I tested this control in my SPO with below array, it works well here:

[image]

[image]

Below is my test demo, you may take a look:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/SPFx-1/blob/master/spfx-pnp-peoplepicker/src/webparts/spfxPnpPeoplepicker/components/SpfxPnpPeoplepicker.tsx

Comment: Hi Baker, I decided not to use the above (my op) as it wasn't efficient and was mutating the state somewhere I couldn't pinpoint. I ended up using es6 [...myArray], ...[newArray] etc.